Perform decryption of AES 256 encrypted values using DECRYPT in Snowflake
I have a Snowflake table which contains an encrypted field in it called answer
This field was encrypted outside of Snowflake and I wish to know if it is possible to use DECRYPT() in Snowflake to do the decryption of this column.
I can confirm none of the recommended posts in SO match my use-case.
I have tried the following


 select to_varchar(
 decrypt(
     to_binary(
         'An encrypted String', 'HEX'
     ),
     'AES Key provided by the Encryption Team'
 ),
 'utf-8') as decrt




Error -
The following string is not a legal hex-encoded value:


     set passphrase = 'AES Key provided by the Encryption Team'
     select decrypt('An Encrypted String', $passphrase)



Error - Invalid argument types for function 'DECRYPT': (VARCHAR(48), VARCHAR(64))

No. DECRYPT only works with data encrypted using the Snowflake ENCRYPT function. If you wanted to decrypt it you would need to use the same system that encrypted it. Assuming that system had the appropriate API/interface, you could use an External Function to call that API and decrypt the data

No, that's not possible, as the derived encryption / decryption key doesn't just depend on the passphrase but also on a Snowflake internal seed.
From the documentation

Snowflake uses the PBKDF2 key-derivation function with a Snowflake-internal seed to compute the encryption/decryption key from the given passphrase.

Because of this key derivation, the encrypt/decrypt function cannot be used to:

Decrypt data that was externally encrypted.

Encrypt data that will be externally decrypted.



PBKDF2 is standardized, so you could create a compatible scheme if you'd work the other way. However, every bit of the encryption / decryption key depends on the seed, so as long as that seed is not known and used by the external encryption code then decryption will fail.
